# I think I need to pass props to child component?

Tags: react-native

The commented section of the code was working as intended, but I want to dynamically build this screen, so I have attempted to take the commented code out and put it in its own `.js` file.

Clearly I am doing something wrong because I'm now hitting an issue with `props.navigation.navigate` being undefined. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

> This code functions correctly if you were to uncomment and remove 'FirstKey'

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { ScrollView, View, StyleSheet, Image } from 'react-native';

    import HomeButton from '../components/HomeButton';
    import FuncButton from '../components/FuncButton';
    import TextBold from '../components/TextBold';
    import TextRegular from '../components/TextRegular';

    import FirstKey from '../components/environments/FirstKey';

    const FirstKeyScreen = props => {

        /*
        // Temporary Array of Names
        var firstKeyArray = [ 
            "THE BLUE TENT", 
            "THE SACRED BREAT", 
            "LEAF IN THE WIND",
            "TOUCH OF LIGHT",
            "THE WATERFALL",
            "CAVE AND CARVING STONE",
            "THE GREAT RAVINE" ];

        createFirstKeyFuncButtons = () => {
            let funcButtons = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < firstKeyArray.length; i++) {
                funcButtons.push(<FuncButton key={i} title={firstKeyArray[i]} onPress={() => {
                            props.navigation.navigate('Player', { title: firstKeyArray[i] })}}
                        />);

            }
            return funcButtons;
        }
        */

        return (
            <ScrollView>
                <View style={styles.screen}>
                    <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <HomeButton style={{width: 150, height: 150}} onPress={() => {
                            props.navigation.navigate({routeName: 'Home'})}}
                        />
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <FirstKey />
                        {/*
                        <TextBold style={styles.titleFont}>FIRST KEY ENVIRONMENTS</TextBold>
                        {this.createFirstKeyFuncButtons()}
                        */}
                    </View>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    };

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        screen: {
            flex: 1,
            paddingBottom: 10
        },
        buttonContainer: {
            marginTop: 20,
            alignItems: 'center',
        },
        titleFont: {
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontSize: 32,
            paddingBottom: 20,
            paddingTop: 50
        }
    });

    export default FirstKeyScreen;
```

Here is my attempt to yank that code out and put it in it's own file (FirstKey.js)

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

    import FuncButton from '../FuncButton';
    import TextBold from '../TextBold';
    import TextReguar from '../TextRegular';

    const FirstKey = props => {

        // Temporary Array of Names
        var firstKeyArray = [ 
            "THE BLUE TENT", 
            "THE SACRED BREAT", 
            "LEAF IN THE WIND",
            "TOUCH OF LIGHT",
            "THE WATERFALL",
            "CAVE AND CARVING STONE",
            "THE GREAT RAVINE" ];

        createFirstKeyFuncButtons = () => {
            let funcButtons = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < firstKeyArray.length; i++) {
                funcButtons.push(<FuncButton key={i} title={firstKeyArray[i]} onPress={() => {
                    props.navigation.navigate('Player', { title: firstKeyArray[i] })}}
                />);

            }
            return funcButtons;
        }

        return (
            <View>
                <TextBold style={styles.titleFont}>FIRST KEY ENVIRONMENTS</TextBold>
                {this.createFirstKeyFuncButtons()}
            </View>
        );
    }

    styles = StyleSheet.create({
        titleFont: {
            textAlign: 'center',
            fontSize: 32,
            paddingBottom: 20,
            paddingTop: 50
        }
    });

    export default FirstKey;
```

My assumption is that the props being called inside of the `FirstKey.js` file is pointing to itself and no to the one in `FirstKeyScreen.js`
I imagine the solution is staring me in the face, but I just dont see it. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `const FirstKey = ({navigation}) => {...` and then `navigation.navigate(...` without `props.`

and:

```
<View>
                        <FirstKey navigation={props.navigation} /> <---CHANGE
                        {/*
                        <TextBold style={styles.titleFont}>FIRST KEY ENVIRONMENTS</TextBold>
                        {this.createFirstKeyFuncButtons()}
                        */}
                    </View>
```

Comment: No dice. 
Error reads: 
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.navigate')

Comment: what is the parent of `FirstKey`? Can you post the code of it?

Comment: There is no parent to FirstKey. I made the component specifically for it to be called inside of FirstKeyScreen. 

Unless I'm not understanding your question.

Comment: I upvoted your answer, but I'm new to this so I don't know if that's all I can do to show that it is a valid solution. Also, your edit overwrote the bit about changing props to ({navigation}), which is still a necessary step. Thanks again!

Comment: Unfortunately, it says that votes cast by users with fewer than 15 reputation do not display publicly =(. This is a new account, and I only have 3 haha

Answer (score 0):

onPress={() => {  props.navigation.navigate('Player', { title: firstKeyArray[i] })}}

first you pass wrong way !

setp 1  your array firstkeyArray[i] push in some array

ex:    var temp=[]

```
  for (let i = 0; i < firstKeyArray.length; i++) {
    ->    temp.push(firstKeyArray[i]); 
       funcButtons.push(<FuncButton key={i} title={firstKeyArray[i]} onPress={() => {
    ->               props.navigation.navigate('Player', { title: temp })}}
                />);
```